# How to check which applications are using the most resources on a server via command line?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I am connected to my server via SSH and would like to find out what's bogging it down so much. What commands should I run from the command line that will tell me which applications are being run and which ones are using up the most resources?

I think my server is running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running a *nix (you did say you thought you were running ubuntu) try using the command

> top

if you want to change the way some of the information is presented to you just run

> man top

and that should pull up the help file.

The command

> ps aux

is also handy for finding out what is running on your server.

Answer (score 6):

htop is good, you might need to get the package via the package manager

Answer (score 6):

Using `ps` and a little command-line fu you can sort processes by CPU usage:

```
ps -Ao pcpu,pid,args | sort -r -k1
```

if you'd like to be able to page through it:

```
ps -Ao pcpu,pid,args | sort -r -k1 | less
```

Example output:

```
%CPU   PID COMMAND
 4.4  5229 perl -e print 1 while 1
 0.2  5202 sshd: root@pts/0
 0.1  5205 -bash
 0.0     9 [events/1]
 0.0   936 [kedac]
 0.0     8 [events/0]
 0.0     7 [watchdog/1]
 0.0     6 [ksoftirqd/1]
 0.0     5 [migration/1]
 0.0  5232 less
 0.0  5231 sort -r -k1
 0.0  5230 ps -Ao pcpu,pid,args
 0.0     4 [watchdog/0]
 0.0   454 /sbin/udevd -d
 0.0   421 [kauditd]
 0.0  4049 /usr/sbin/pure-uploadscript -B -r /root/handler.sh
 0.0  4046 pure-ftpd (SERVER)
 0.0     3 [ksoftirqd/0]
 0.0   395 [kjournald]
```

Comment: Oooh, I like, thanks for posting.  I changed the pipe to less to be "grep -v '^ 0.0'" to get rid of all the processes not worth mentioning.

Comment: Also, need to add --numeric to the sort to get proper sorting.

Comment: Usually I just grab the first 10 with `head` as one of them is the culprit I'm looking for. The issue with using `-n` to sort is that the header will be moved down, using it without has always sorted it for me properly asciibetically. Modify it according to your fancy. I have a similar command aliased to "`hogs`" :)

Answer (score 1):

(h)top gives you CPU usage and memory. You can also use `iotop` for disk read/write, and other IO stuff. Probably not installed by default, so run `sudo apt-get install iotop` first..